# Howler.js - The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, howler.js

I am trying to trigger an alarm after a certain time has ended. I am using Howler.js to play the alarm, but for some reason, it is displaying this error: `howler.js:2500 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.` I switched to Howler because a similar error was coming when I tried to use Audio() Web API in JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
const { Howl, Howler } = require("howler");

let i;
let timer;
var alarm = new Howl({
  src: ["alarm.mp3"],
});
let playTimer = true;
const timerDisplay = document.getElementById("timerDisplay");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  i = 5;

  timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (playTimer == true) {
      if (i != 0) {
        timerDisplay.textContent = i;
        i--;
      }

      if (i == 0) {
        alarm.play();
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

I don't know if this is helpful or not, but just to let you know, I am using Parcel as my bundler. Thank you in advance for any answer.

Comment: The error is quite clear: you need a user gesture before you can start the audio context. You could do this by adding a "start" button to your page, for example. Or any other kind of user interaction.

Comment: @Kokodoko I did mention in the question that I want to trigger it after a certain amount of time (when `i` goes down to 0).

Comment: The problem is that audio is not allowed on a webpage unless there is some user interaction first. You can't start audio automatically when a page first loads. Not even with a timer.

Comment: Hmmm... So is there any hack which I can implement to make it work?

Comment: No, it's a browser feature, intended to prevent unwanted audio playing. I mostly solve it by adding some user interaction such as a start button or a mute/unmute button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kokodoko said in the comments of my question, the audio had to be triggered by some form of user interaction. So, I added a button in my HTML and replaced the

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {})`

with

`startTimerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {})`

So this is the final code:

```
const { Howl, Howler } = require("howler");

let i;
let timer;
var alarm = new Howl({
  src: ["alarm.mp3"],
});
let playTimer = true;
const timerDisplay = document.getElementById("timerDisplay");
const startTimerBtn = document.getElementById("startTimer");

startTimerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  i = 5;

  timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (playTimer == true) {
      if (i != 0) {
        timerDisplay.textContent = i;
        i--;
      }

      if (i == 0) {
        alarm.play();
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

Although this wasn't the solution I intended to get, it suits my needs well.

Also, one small other thing for others using Parcel.js like me. Just in case you don't know, you have to put your audio file in Parcel's dist directory so that it can play. For some reason, it wasn't bundling automatically.